# Android NativeActivity OpenGL-ES native app: How to get a less than full screen surface

Tags: android, native-code, egl

I have native Android app  using Google's native_app_glue wrapper.  I would like to obtain a less than full-screen  surface  for rendering GLES into.  In GLES apps using java layer derived from Activity  this is accomplished by getWindow().setLayer() in Java layer. However, my project situation doesn't allow me to use  this solution.

With nativeActivtiy and native_app_glue layer I can use  JNI to  get the Java classes  and callback into Java,  but not modify the View hierarchy. When calling back to setLayers() from my C code via JNI, I get this error since the NativeActivity is not in the same thread as the View hierarchy was created in.

E/AndroidRuntime(21503): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

And here is my code to do this:

```
// Call Java to set  Window size
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int CallJavaWindowSize(struct android_app* state, jint width, jint height)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    jclass nativeActivityClass;
    jobject nativeActivityObj;
    jmethodID mid;
    jobject windowObj;
    bool didAttachment = false;
    int ret = -1;
    JavaVMAttachArgs JVMAttachArgs;

    jint result = state->activity->vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6); 

    if (!env  && result == JNI_EDETACHED)
    {
        JVMAttachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        JVMAttachArgs.name = "NativeThread";
        JVMAttachArgs.group = NULL;
        if (state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) < 0)
        {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() Failed to attach to thread");
            return ret;
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() attached to Thread");
        didAttachment = true;
    }
    else if (result < 0)
    {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() Failed to GetEnv()");
            return ret;
    }

    // retrieves NativeActivity class
    nativeActivityObj = state->activity->clazz;
    //nativeActivityClass = env->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");
    nativeActivityClass = env->GetObjectClass(nativeActivityObj);
    if (!nativeActivityClass)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() Failed to Find NativeActivity class");
        return ret;
    }

    //Run getWindow().setLayout(width,height)
    mid = env->GetMethodID(nativeActivityClass, "getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
    if (mid == 0)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() Failed to get method getWindow() with signature = ()Landroid/view/Window;");
        return ret;
    }

    windowObj = env->CallObjectMethod(nativeActivityObj, mid);
    if (windowObj == 0)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "PowerLift", "CallJavaWindowSize() Failed to CallObjectMethod for mid getWindow()");
        return ret;
    }

    jclass classWindow = env->FindClass("android/view/Window");
    mid = env->GetMethodID(classWindow, "setLayout", "(II)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(windowObj, mid, width, height);


    if (didAttachment)
        state->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();

    return 0;
}
```

A solution some of you may suggest is to use glViewport() to draw to less than full-screen. This solution works visually but is poor performance as EGL driver is still handling fullscreen surfaces.

I am  wondering if this approach is the best solution as it is architecturally quite a change from using native app wrapper:
a) ditch native app glue wrapper and run native code (or at least a portion of it) in same thread as JVM
b) derive from NativeActivity  a Java class that creates the View hierarchy via setContentView()
c) in Native code that is running in same thread as Java  use JNI to call setLayout()
d) rest of native code can be running  in a different thread as needed

I am not sure if the above approach is feasible of if I will run into a roadblock with this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're tring to render out from a pixel buffer, you might want to use `glSubTexImage2D()`.